# How can I make it so can only see one accoridion panel at a time?

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

I know there are a few of these questions already on here but I've tried and none of them work unfortunately.

Any help would be much appreciated! All I want is to be able to collapse the other panels when another is opened.

Here is my current js script:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active1");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Iterate through all the elements, searching for elements that already have active1 and remove the class before you toggle the new active class..

Answer (score 0):

Without more details I cannot be sure that this would work, but including a loop through all your accordions and doing the opposite of how you open them should do the trick. If you want more help, an example of the CSS and HTML would be necessary.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].classList.remove('active1');
      var panel = acc[i].nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
    }
    this.classList.add("active1");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```